# Iconv byte length

Tags: php, utf-8, iconv, cp1251

I am using iconv to convert string from CP1251 to UTF-8
Problem is that string length before conversion is 4 bytes, after 8.

After converting i send message to Apple servers, where is length is limited.

How I can get conversion and keep the same length?

Comment: You can't.. guess why UTF-8 has 8 at end :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Comment: I give bad example, conversion doubles the length of string.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can do it. In UTF-8 one-byte codes are used only for the ASCII values 0 through 127. In this case the UTF-8 code has the same value as the ASCII code. The high-order bit of these codes is always 0.

As you are trying to encode non-ASCII characters, you'll get more, then 1 byte per character.

[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Overlong_encodings